# No compatible method found: error while passing object to a method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I am trying to write junit for some old legacy code we have

Below is the method in DataLogger class for which I am writing junit and I am using jmockit -

```
private Object[] extractMessageObjects(final Object... objects) {
    Object[] result = new Object[objects.length - 1];

    System.arraycopy(objects, 0, result, 0, result.length);

    return result;
}
```

So below test should work fine. Right?

```
@Test
public void testLogDebugWithStackTrace() {
    DataLogger logger = DataLogger.getInstance(ClientTest.class);

    Object obj[] = new Object[] {1};
    Deencapsulation.invoke(logger, "extractMessageObjects", obj);
}
```

But I am getting exception as -

```
No compatible method found: extractMessageObjects(java.lang.Integer)
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `invoke(..)` method you use, the type of the parameters for the method are resolved from the type of elements in your `Object[]`. Since yours contains an `Integer`, jmockit will try to find a method that accepts and `Integer`. It will fail since such a method doesn't exist.

```
No compatible method found: extractMessageObjects(java.lang.Integer)
```

Instead, you can use the overloaded method that accepts the parameter types

```
Deencapsulation.invoke(new Example(), "extractMessageObjects",
            new Class<?>[] { Object[].class }, (Object) new Object[] { 1 });
```

So that it can find the appropriate method correctly without hints from the type of arguments you use. Note that you have to cast the last argument so that it is used as the only element in the target `Object[]` parameter of the `Deencapsulation.invoke(..)` method.

Comment: Thanks `Sotirios`. It works fine. One more silly question. I also have similar method like this `private Throwable extractThrowable(final Object... objects) {
 return (Throwable) lastOf(objects);
    }` like this which also accepts objects varg array. But in this I am not sure what should I pass an input parameter since it return throwable? Any thoughts?

Comment: @AKIWEB Something similar to this solution except it would need to contain an object you can cast to `Throwable`.

Comment: hmmm.. Can you provide an example on this if  possible as well?

Comment: @AKIWEB Instead of the `1` in the invocation in my answer, pass an object that is a sub type of `Throwable`. This is very use case dependent. I don't really have an example.

Comment: Sure. In my case, I just need to pass anything so that I can cover those lines of code. I did like this `invoke(logger, "extractThrowable", new Class<?>[] { Object[].class }, UnknownHostException.class);` But it gives `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: @AKIWEB What does the `IllegalArgumentException` say?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51026/discussion-between-akiweb-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: :Can you also see what's wrong with this solution I have in the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170907/how-to-increase-the-conditional-coverage-using-jmockit-for-cobertura/23170945). In my opinion, I am covering all the possible cases but still coverage is not going up. If you can help me out then it will be of great help.