# Deencapsulation.invoke method is throwing exception with message "IllegalArgumentException: No compatible method found"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

`Deencapsulation.invoke()` throws exception with message if I pass an instance of subclass as argument to private method `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No compatible method found`.

Like this:

```
Object a = new ClassB();
try
{
    Deencapsulation.invoke(someInstance, "someMethod", a);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then console shows output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No compatible method found: someMethod(ClassB)
```

How do I should call the private method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No compatible method found: error while passing object to a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171798/no-compatible-method-found-error-while-passing-object-to-a-method)

Comment: No, I won't provide it as an answer. You shouldn't even have asked this question as a little search would have brought you to this duplicate.